# convert an ajax http post to python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, post

I want to send some data to a server using Python.

I have a working piece of code from jQuery which does what I want:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    url: "http://192.168.50.88/emoncms/nodes/1/tx/values",
    data: "17,58,5,1569,0,3000,236"
});
```

I need to do the same thing in Python but I can't see how to do it. Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
import httplib, urllib
newdata = "17,58, 5,1569, 0, 3000, 236"
headers = {"Content-type": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("192.168.50.88")
conn.request("POST", "/emoncms/nodes/1/tx/values", newdata)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
conn.close()
```

This prints: "200 OK" so the basic post is working but my data doesn't reach the server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A side question: Is a quotation sign missing in line `headers = ...`?

Comment: Yes, you're right I missed one in the copy/paste somehow. I've edited to put it in.

Comment: check out flask module, specifically the json.dumps() function

Answer (score 2):

Use requests instead.

```
import requests
requests.post(
    'http://192.168.50.88/emoncms/nodes/1/tx/values',
    data='17,58, 5,1569, 0, 3000, 236',
    headers={'content-type': 'text/plain'}
)
```

you can also store the response by doing this...

```
r = requests.post(...)
```

and then you can access the response code, any attached data, headers etc from that r variable.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I've just tried this. It still doesn't work,however. Printing r.status_code gives 200 so the post itself is fine but the server is obviously discarding the data. I'm installing wireshark to see if I can see any difference in the format between the ajax and Python versions.

Comment: After investigating with Wireshark and proving that the Ajax and Python requests send identical posts (apart from identifying the browser diferently in the header - as you'd expect). I've realised that I also need to send an apikey to send data to this particular database. The browser is sending a cookie. I need to send the apikey explicitly. Thanks for your help atlspin - using requests is much neater than my original version.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question - The problem is the particular target I'm trying to send data to, an energy logging program running on a raspberry pi, needs an api key before it will accept the data.

If anyone's interested the equipment is detailed on http://openenergymonitor.org/

Thanks to atlspin for much clearer code than my own.