# Use python to scrape a webpage that changes based on a drop-down menu

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I've been trying to get data from http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/dal/historical using python(version 3.5.1) automatically. As part of this I need to change the timeframe from the default of 3 months to 2 years using the site's drop-down menu. The  source looks like this:

```
<h4>Get up to 10 years of daily historical stock prices &amp; volumes.</h4>
<div class="floatL">
    <p>Select the Timeframe:</p>
</div>
<div class="floatL marginT10px fontS14px">
    <select id="ddlTimeFrame" name="ddlTimeFrame" onchange="getQuotes(false)">
        <option value="5d">5 Days</option>
        <option value="1m">1 Month</option>
        <option value="3m" selected="selected">3 Months</option>
        <option value="6m">6 Months</option>
        <option value="1y">1 Year</option>
        <option value="18m">18 Months</option>
        <option value="2y">2 Years</option>
        <option value="3y">3 Years</option>
        <option value="4y">4 Years</option>
        <option value="5y">5 Years</option>
        <option value="6y">6 Years</option>
        <option value="7y">7 Years</option>
        <option value="8y">8 Years</option>
        <option value="9y">9 Years</option>
        <option value="10y">10 Years</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clearB"></div>
<div class="realtiveP">
    <div id="ajaxloader" class="ajax_loading_wrap" style="display:none">
        <img src="http://www.nasdaq.com/images/ajax-loader-2.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="ajax loader" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've already written code which successfully reads the webpage, but I haven't been able to change the time frame from 3 months. In fact, manually selecting from the list changes the page but not the source. Here's the code I used:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url="http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/dal/historical"
pageInputs={"ddlTimeFrame":"2y"}
pageGets = urllib.parse.urlencode(pageInputs)
pageGets=pageGets.encode("ascii")
serReq=urllib.request.Request(url,pageGets)
opReq=urllib.request.urlopen(serReq)
rdReq=opReq.read()
dcReq=rdReq.decode()
```

Like I said, reading through the webpage works just fine. I need to find a way to change the time frame from the default value.

Comment: http://niimh.nic.in/ebooks/ecaraka/?mod=read

Comment: how to scrape above site please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to collect just the data(not the whole page), below is the source code of function getQuotes(download) you would consider.

```
function getQuotes(download) {
        if (!download)
            showLoadingSpinner();

        var data = $("[id$='ddlTimeFrame']").val();
        var submitString = data + '|' + download + "|" + quoteBoxSelectedSymbol; if (!download) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl,
                data: submitString,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("[id$='historicalContainer']").html(response);
                    $(".genTable tbody tr:odd").addClass("genTablealt");
                    hideLoadingSpinner();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $("[id$='submitString']").val(submitString);
            $("#getFile").submit();
        }
    }
```

Actual parameters used:

```
url: "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/dal/historical",
data: "2y|false|DAL"
```

But you have to deal with **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing** issue since they seems to deny resource request from other hosts.

Comment: And if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is `onchange="getQuotes(false)"`

If you ctrl-f "getQuotes", you will find the ajax call:

```
function getQuotes(download) {
    if (!download)
        showLoadingSpinner();

    var data = $("[id$='ddlTimeFrame']").val();
    var submitString = data + '|' + download + "|" + quoteBoxSelectedSymbol; if (!download) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl,
            data: submitString,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("[id$='historicalContainer']").html(response);
                $(".genTable tbody tr:odd").addClass("genTablealt");
                hideLoadingSpinner();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("[id$='submitString']").val(submitString);
        $("#getFile").submit();
    }
}
```

To convert an AJAX call to python see [convert an ajax http post to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614243/convert-an-ajax-http-post-to-python)

The response will contain the data within `<tr>` tags

Example:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.post('http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical',
        data='10y|false|AAPL', headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.select('tr')
for row in rows[1:]:
    td = row.find_all('td')
    date = td[0].text.strip()
    open = td[1].text.strip()
    high = td[2].text.strip()
    low = td[3].text.strip()
    close = td[4].text.strip()
    volume = td[5].text.strip()
    ...
```